# Upload images using AFNetworking 1.3.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, afnetworking

I want to upload images to server(openstack run RESTFUL service)
I using AFNetworking 1.3.3

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"upload/" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataToUpload name:@"attachment" fileName:@"attachment.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
}];
```

File is uploaded to server has type

```
"content_type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
```

When I download from server I can't get exactly image because I use multipartFormRequest.
Which function for me to upload? Thanks.

Comment: How does your headers look (and how do you set them)? The method you are using is the right one and have always worked for me. The type of your file is actually header fields, namely the "content_type" for example.

Comment: My header: "Content-Type: $ContentType" "X-Auth-Token: $token" I set Content-Type is "image/jpeg", or any. When I downloaded is fail, Expected content type {(
    ...
    "image/x-win-bitmap"
)}, got multipart/form-data